# array coming back as an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

why is this coming back as an Object rather than an Array?

how do I use the map function on this?

```html
[ { _id: 590bbb88858367c9bb07776e,
    status: 2,
    id: 590bba9c858367c9bb077759 },
  { _id: 590bbb95858367c9bb07776f,
    status: 2,
    id: 590bbad5858367c9bb07775f },
  { _id: 590bbb9e858367c9bb077770,
    status: 2,
    id: 590bbb05858367c9bb077765 },
  { _id: 590bbbaa858367c9bb077771,
    status: 2,
    id: 590bbaf2858367c9bb077763 },
  { _id: 590bbbb6858367c9bb077772,
    status: 2,
    id: 590bbae5858367c9bb077761 },
  { _id: 590bbbc5858367c9bb077773,
    status: 2,
    id: 590bbabe858367c9bb07775d },
  { _id: 590bbbef858367c9bb077774,
    status: 2,
    id: 590bbab2858367c9bb07775b } ]
object
```

Comment: Turn what in to Array? Your data is already an array

Comment: That's an array.

Comment: Your username goes well with your question hehe. As the others already stated, this is an array - See the brackeys `[]` that wraps your objects

Comment: Arrays **are** objects.

Comment: I want to be able to use the map function, which only works on Arrays, but doesn't on this.

Comment: @totalnoob It works fine on this, your not using it correctly then. Can you provide what your trying to do?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek, trying to do this     friends = friends.map(function(v) {
      delete(v._id);
      delete(v.status);
      return v;
    }); TypeError: friends.map is not a function

Comment: @totalnoob [That works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/vkr83ytn/) if `friends` is the value you claim it is in this Question. Check and make sure `friends` is the value you are expecting.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek, you're right it does work fine in vanilla js. somehow it doesn't work when it's done through express

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek, one interesting thing is when I added it into vanilla js, I had to add quotes for the _id values. Because in Mongoose, the type of _id in the Schema is ObjectId, but when it comes back as an array of objects,  that field comes back without any quotes but can be nothing other than a string.

Answer (score 1):

It *is* coming back as an array - an array of objects.

You can tell it is an array because it starts and ends with `[brackets]`.

The objects inside are defined with `{braces}`.

So it is an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript arrays are objects.

If you use `typeof`, you will get `object`. You should use `Array.isArray()` instead:

```js
var arr = [];

console.log(typeof arr);
console.log(Array.isArray(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

`typeof` an array will result into `object` as this operator (`typeof`) returns "object" for arrays because **in JavaScript arrays are objects**. [Docs](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_datatypes.asp)

In order to further check on arrays you can use `isArray()` function. [More details](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isarray.asp)